# How to include relation with another entity, when using UserManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP Identity's `UserManager` to fetch users in particular roles.

```
var members = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Member");
var leaders = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Leader");
```

My problem is that my `User` entity has a relation to another entity. Normally I would do in the data context:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AppUser>> GetUsersAsync()
{
        return await _context.Users
            .Include(u => u.Projects)
            .Include(u => u.School)
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

But there is no `Include` method for `UserManager`. What would be the alternative here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using the same syntax you posted for data context. But here use your original user list instead of taking users from context.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AppUser>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    return await _context.users
        .Include(u => u.Projects)
        .Include(u => u.School)
        .Where(u => members.Contains(m.Name)) //filter criteria...
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

This should get you all related entities from the existing users which you earlier got from userManager.
`UserManager` is only a wrapper over the user store and it provides you with a different set of users as per role.

Comment: I don't think I understand. I should call user manager first, and then the method in data context?

Comment: Noi. you should first get all users ( i.e. members or leaders from userManager ) the way you are already getting and then write down your link query to fetch all related users from users.  _context.Users won't be used. Instead, you will use members or leaders. Try this and let me know if it works?

Comment: That is the problem that I have. GetUsersInRole return IList<AppUser>, instead of IQueryable, hence I cannot use Include()

Comment: This would return you the in-memory users which is List. Here the query is already executed and there is also no chance to get all related entities from userManager way either. Get the users and include them. Where clause to filter them out in the second query.

Comment: Updated the answer. I think you could achieve similar result what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> But there is no Include method for UserManager. What would be the
> alternative here?

Try to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` , the we can use Include method for UserManager like:

```
            await _userManager.Users     
            .Include(u => u.Projects)
            .Include(u => u.School)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah, that could be the solution. But it's in EntityFrameworkCore and not sure if he is using Entity FrameworkCore or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `UserManager<TUser>` class has a [`Users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.users?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-1-users) property which is an `IQueryable<TUser>`. This means you can use Entity Framework LINQ operators on it as you would on any other `DbSet`/`IQueryable`:

```cs
 await _userManager.Users
            .Include(u => u.Projects)
            .Include(u => u.School)
            .ToListAsync();
```